# Get file download link in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, download, href

I'm trying to download some files in my web application. Apparently I placed the files to be downloaded in a folder inside the controllers folder, somewhat similar to this:

```
controllers/upload/project_name/bc68gdas9jfeh9yfj/file.dat
```

Apparently I want to download file.dat but I don't know what to put in my  tag for my links. What do I put in my href so I could download the said file?

Answer (score 11):

You don't need to place the downloadable files inside the `controllers` folder, instead keep the files in the root of your project, but if its really necessary to keep the files in the controllers folder(which imho is not a good choice), try this:

```
function your_function(){
    $this->load->helper('download');
    $data = file_get_contents(APPPATH . 'controllers/upload/project_name/bc68gdas9jfeh9yfj/'.$this->uri->segment(3)); // Read the file's contents
    $name = $this->uri->segment(3);
    force_download($name, $data);
}
```

Just link the file like this:

```
<a title="Click to download" href="<?php echo base_url() ?>your_controller/your_function/<?php echo $file_name; ?>" >Download</a>
```

Answer (score -1):

There you go, use this :

http://webdesign.about.com/od/beginningtutorials/ht/download_link.htm

hope it helps